How to debug a zip deployment of a Python Azure Function?
I'm deploying a Python application as an Azure Functions App through a zip deployment. The project structure looks like this:
src/
├── lib
├── modules
    ├── __init__.py
    └── trivy/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── fetch_release.py
        ├── send_notification.py
        ├── main.py
        └── adaptive_card_template.json
├── __init.py__
├── .funcignore
├── function_app.py
├── host.json
├── requirements.txt
└── local.settings.json
pyproject.toml
poetry.lock

where I only zip the src folder as it is the root of the Functions project.
The problem I am facing is that after running the following az command:
az functionapp deployment source config-zip --src ./dist/dependency-webhook-api.zip --resource-group ${AZURE_APP_RG} --name ${AZURE_APP_NAME} --subscription ${AZURE_APP_SUBSCRIPTION} --timeout 180


The result indicates that the operation is a success, however the Function app does not display any functions on its GUI:

| It has to be noted that I successfully ran the application locally using func start
These are the most important files:
function_app.py
# The function_app.py file is the main Azure functions initializer,
# here the app object gets created, and other functions,
# get registered to it.

import azure.functions as func

# Imports of azure functions from modules:
from modules.trivy.main import trivy_module

# Init the azure functions app
app = func.FunctionApp()

# Register azure functions from modules
app.register_functions(trivy_module)

host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Warning",
      "Host.Aggregator": "Trace",
      "Host.Results": "Information",
      "Function": "Information"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

modules/trivy/main.py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

from lib.utils import ReleaseMode, newer_version_available

from .fetch_release import fetch_release_data
from .send_notification import send_notification

trivy_module = func.Blueprint()


@trivy_module.function_name(name="trivy_module")
@trivy_module.timer_trigger(
    schedule="0 12 * * 1", arg_name="timer", run_on_startup=True
)
def main(timer: func.TimerRequest):
    logging.info("Trivy module triggered.")
    response = fetch_release_data()
    logging.info("Trivy release data fetched.")
    if newer_version_available(ReleaseMode.MINOR_MODE, "v0.48.0", response["tag_name"]):
        send_notification(response)
        logging.info("Trivy notification update sent.")

EDIT: Added the requirements.txt:
azure-functions==1.20.0 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"
certifi==2024.7.4 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"
charset-normalizer==3.3.2 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"
idna==3.7 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"
requests==2.32.3 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"
urllib3==2.2.2 ; python_version >= "3.11" and python_version < "4.0"

If I run the az functionapp with the --build-remote true parameter, this is the output:

If anyone has any idea how I can debug this deployment to see any error or why the application won't start as needed, your help would be much appreciated!

It is important to note that the deployment is successful, probably because there are no actual errors in the zip deployment - but also no functions are being recognised. I assume this is because of the relative module imports I have in my Python code. Is there a way to see the Python debugging or error output?

Provide your requirements.txt.

Hi @Pravallika KV, I have edited the post and added the requirements.txt file. It is also included in the src directory that gets zipped (the src directory is the root of the zip, meaning there is not src/ dir in the zip).

Can you share github repo of your code if possible(excluding sensitive info if available)

I have replicated the original project (hosted on a private GitLab) and removed sensitive information: https://github.com/Vanja-S/Copy-of-azure-functions

Deploy src folder using command func azure functionapp publish functionappname, I'm able to deploy using the same process. refer image

Is there a way to automate this deployment process? As far as I'm aware Microsoft does not provide a docker image with the func command.
EDIT: You can post your answer and I will accept it, since that was the original question.

I have followed below steps and able to deploy the function code you have provided to Azure function app.

Install Azure function core tools using command:

npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true


Navigate to Copy-of-azure-functions\src in CLI.
Deploy the function to Azure using the command func azure functionapp publish <functionapp_name>:

C:\Users\uname\Copy-of-azure-functions\src>func azure functionapp publish kpfn08
Getting site publishing info...
[2024-08-13T12:00:46.269Z] Starting the function app deployment...
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING app setting.
Removing WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting.
Creating archive for current directory...
Performing remote build for functions project.
Uploading 12.52 KB [##############################################################################]
Remote build in progress, please wait...
Updating submodules.
Preparing deployment for commit id 'de7a8d14-e'.
PreDeployment: context.CleanOutputPath False
PreDeployment: context.OutputPath /home/site/wwwroot
Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
Running oryx build...
Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.11 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues

Oryx Version: 0.2.20230210.1, Commit: a49c8f6b8abbe95bc884dea7fd0d86e, ReleaseTagName: 20230210.1

//Removed few logs

Number of duplicate files found 22
Number of inodes 416
Number of files 365
Number of fragments 26
Number of symbolic links  0
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 51
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
Number of uids 1
        root (0)
Number of gids 1
        root (0)
Creating placeholder blob for linux consumption function app...
SCM_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE placeholder blob scm-latest-kpfn08.zip located
Uploading built content /home/site/artifacts/functionappartifact.squashfs for linux consumption function app...
Resetting all workers for kpfn08.azurewebsites.net
Deployment successful. deployer = Push-Deployer deploymentPath = Functions App ZipDeploy. Extract zip. Remote build.
Remote build succeeded!
[2024-08-13T12:01:39.753Z] Syncing triggers...
Functions in kpfn08:
    trivy_module - [timerTrigger]


Deployed the function to Azure:


